# Custom Action and Group

Tags: custom-actions

I'm creating a link and put it in the site action container.
The link should only be visible to members in the HR groups.
Here is the declaration in my Elements.xml file

```
 <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Rights="ManageWeb" Id="UM" Description="View and manage user profile"   
    Title="User Management" GroupId="SiteActions"  
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu" Sequence="10">
    <UrlAction Url="~site/_layouts/UM/Overview.aspx"  />
  </CustomAction>

  <HideCustomAction HideActionId="UM" GroupId="SiteActions"  
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu" Id="hideUM"  > 
  </HideCustomAction>
```

My problems is how do I connect this two, between the link and the group.
Any help is very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intention of HideCustomAction is to permanently hide the custom action, not to hide it conditionally, so you cannot link those two out of the box. The custom action can hide itself based on two attributes of CustomAction element: Rights and RequireSiteAdministrator as documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460194.aspx

OUt of the box, you can hide it based on permissions of the user, not based on user's group membership.